# how to display pictures in columns on the same page

Tags: multiple-columns, visualization

This is what I'd like to do. I'd like to be able to display several pics in columns (2,3) on the same webpage to compare them on the right hand side of the menu which would be in the margin on the left. Many thanks for your help.
(I've got a scalar.edu site which uses html)

Comment: please rewrite your question, add where you want to display those columns, which language/platform etc.

Answer (score 0):

On a http://scalar.usc.edu/ book site in the page edit mode on the toolbar at top of the text edit area there is an option to "Paste from Word". You can create the table you want in MS Word or Libre Office and copy the entire table to clipboard, then paste it using this button. Worked for me with Libre Office 5 Write.

The table borders are by default not visible in Scalar and one way to make this positioning easier is that while in word editor add a letter of text to each cell in the table. Once copied and pasted into scalar you can select the letter with your mouse and delete it and the cursor will be positioned so you can use the toolbar option on the right to Insert Inline Scalar Media Link. You will need to import content to be able to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'd like to do something else. click several times in a menu to display 1,2,3 pictures on the same webpage, something similar to what can be done in powerpoint.